# How does Captain Phasma type with thimbles on her fingers?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

How does Captain Phasma type her password to deactivate the shield protecting Starkiller Base when she is wearing thimbles on her fingers?

[image: Looking good, Captain Phasma!]

Comment: Very well, thanks for asking.

Comment: I can't help but think your question [reminds me of something...](http://www.hrwiki.org/wiki/How_do_you_type_with_boxing_gloves_on%3F)

Comment: Back up... Why would wearing thimbles on her fingers prevent her from typing a password?  They might make it harder for her to touch type, but I don't see why they'd physically prevent her from pushing keys.

Comment: Large keys and a lot of practice.

Comment: I sometimes see women with long nail extensions working as cashiers, sometimes even on touchscreen computers.  I don't know how it's possible, but I'm quite sure thimbles are less of a problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because she doesn't type to do it (in the film)- it appears to be a dial / handle.

Finn never indicates she should type in a password, he simply says:

```
                        FINN
          You want me to blast that bucket off
          your head? Lower the shields.

                      CAPTAIN PHASMA
               You're making a big mistake.

                      FINN
                     Do it.
```

You can see that there is no standard keyboard on this particular control panel

[image]

Comment: You hear several beeps and boops in the background, indicating that it took more than just pulling a level.

Comment: the beeps and boops aren't necessarily directly related to her actively disabling the shields but could be feedback that the process is starting / completed. Good find in the novel though

Comment: But... If it's just a lever.... Why don't they just pull it themselves? O.o

Comment: @thedarkwanderer They don't know which lever it is.

Answer (score 18):

This is addressed in the film's tie-in novelisations. Apparently the lowering of the shield was accomplished by pushing buttons rather than typing commands on a keyboard.

> *Chewie backed him up with a roar.
>
>   **As Phasma pushed a few buttons,** Finn looked at Han. “Solo, if this works, we’re not going to have a lot of time to find Rey.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Force Awakens: Finn's Story](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Force_Awakens:_Finn's_Story)</sup></sub>

The sequence did not require extensive typing.

> *He planted Phasma at a console and ordered her to initiate the deactivation. When she refused, he pressed his blaster harder against her helmet. “Do it.”
>
>   She did. **A few keystrokes were all it took to bypass the automatic systems** and start the sequence to shut down the shields.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: The Force Awakens: A Junior Novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens:_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>

Comment: might be worth seeing if Pablo would weigh in to resolve the potential conflict between novel and film

Comment: Hm. Typing a password that's no more than say... 10 or 12 characters seems to fit the description of "push[ing] a few buttons" or "a few keystrokes".